# ubuntu 14.04 - USB serial port - device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)

Tags: 14.04, usb, python

After two days of web searching I have to admit that this is beyond me and need some assistance please

I admin several machines(but do not claim to be a Linux admin), mainly running 12.04 LTS - we use a USB to serial adapter for a number of hookups in the lab.
One 12.04 process (for lack of a better word) was to chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0 so that the USB serial adapter can be installed or removed without the users having to do anything and this has worked well, if maybe not the correct way of doing this.
I updated one machine from 12.04 to 14.04 - and the update was seamless.
I had to replace another system, so we purchased a dell running windows 7 that I planned to make dual boot just like all the others.
Was unsuccessful ever loaded 14.04 - ended up loading 12.04 and then upgrading to 14.04 - very painful and exceeding long but finally got 14.04 up and running. 
I am now hung on the USB serial issue - when installed I see it in /dev as ttyUSB0 and I have added the user to group so I can run it but always get the message when I run our python interface script:

device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)

Unfortunately our software developer isn't being helpful so I am hanging on limb here.

Lastly part of loading the python interface is to load two things
1 py.serial
2 google cmdline
Where I may have run off the road is loading these after upgrading to 14.04.
My current plan is to blow 14.04 away, reload 12.04 and get it all working from there - then try and update to 14.04 again.
Would very much apreichiate any assistance before taking that step
Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar Problem. After a recent update of ubuntu 14.04 my serial connections failed. I found this and it worked for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1501240

After booting the 3.13.0-63-generic kernel everything worked again.

btw: instead of chmod 777 every /dev/ttyUSB* you can maybe simply add the user to the group "dialout".

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, I would encourage you to include the fix here as links can break or go down.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer already stated, there seems to be something wrong in the `3.13.0-65-generic` kernel. Until this get fixed, the workaround is to boot the older kernel `3.13.0-63-generic`.

To do this, reboot your PC and when GRUB loads, choose the option `Advanced options for Ubuntu` which will take you to the next menu where you can choose to load the older kernel.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded and all who responded to several other threads to this issue- I loaded synaptic package manager - located what was referenced as the older generic kernel - and took a blind mouse click and it worked - Thanks!!!!!

Comment: It is great that you have solved the problem. You can post your own answer to your question. Make sure to select which answer helped you best solve your problem, so this question is marked as answered.